# How to enable PHP support in Netbeans?

Tags: php, netbeans, ubuntu, netbeans-7, netbeans-plugins

On Ubuntu, I have install netbeans but it does not have any option to start a php project.  I've looked at the plugin list and php is not in the list, neither is it in the plugins to download list.

I've gone to the netbeans website and I am not sure which php plugin to download.

Can someone please help me with this?

Ubuntu 12.04 64bit has netbeans 7.0.1 in the software repository.

Answer (score 106, accepted):

Go to `Tools->Plugins`.

In the `Settings` tab ensure that the update center `Netbeans Distribution` is active.

Then in the `Available Plugins` tab click on `Reload Catalog` and you should see PHP.

Also you have to make your LAMP config, this [link](http://netbeans.org/kb/docs/php/configure-php-environment-ubuntu.html#separate-packages) can help you.

If you have already download the full bundle go in `Installed` tab and activate PHP.

Answer (score 0):

Please try select the php option from this page and install
http://netbeans.org/downloads/index.html

Answer (score 0):

Click on menu **File** > **New Project**
then select **PHP** from the **Categories** list, on click you will see PHP being initialized automatically...

For a detailed answer visit

http://digitdrive.blogspot.in/2013/11/developing-php-project-on-netbeans-ide.html

Answer (score -1):

Goto Tools > Plugins > Available Plugins

search for PHP Enhancements .

But first of all you should download netBeans version that support PHP.

there is 2 available distributions, one for PHP and Javescript, the other one is the fully fledged version that support for many programing languages , PHP is included of course.

any of those to distributions should work will on PHP.