# Neatbeans plugin for php

Tags: php, netbeans, plugins

Please, what plugin need I to install in order to be able to work with php files? When I try to create a new project in this way, File > New Project there is not the category PHP.

Comment: This might help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10473109/how-to-enable-php-support-in-netbeans

Answer (score 0):

my php plugins stack is:

1. Composer
2. Doctrine2
3. Framework
4. PHP PhpDocumentor
5. PHP Manual Search
6. PHP Static Analysis
7. PHPUnit Symfony2 Framework
8. Twig Templates

for more see: http://plugins.netbeans.org/PluginPortal/