# Adding downloaded .js file to existing Project in Netbeans

Tags: java, javascript, web-services, netbeans

I have downloaded a `.js` file to use in my **Java Webservice-Project**. I have using **Netbeans** as the development IDE. I understand how to create a new JavaScript file as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7592171/326820).
However, I am not sure how to add a downloaded file to the existing project structure. I can create a .js file and copy paste the content, but was wondering if it is possible to directly add it. I remember doing similar things on Visual Studio, where we can import existing files by using "Add existing item". I am wondering if similar thing is available on NetBeans.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm using NetBeans in ubuntu and you can just copy the js file into your project folder. You don't need to import or anything like that.

Comment: +1: copying from file browser and pasting in Netbeans project folder works fine :)